# In all games, shadows have small rectangles that flicker

Tags: technical-issues, graphics-card

Graphics card drivers are completely up to date.
Operating systems have been Windows 7 and Windows 10.
Graphics card is a GTX 660M

This happens in multiple different games. WoW, Archeage, H1Z1, Runescape, and more.

---

Take a look at the below screenshots and you'll see exactly what I'm talking about.

-

[image: Screenshot:]

[image: GIF of same image:]

---

My comment below shows more images of this.

Comment: H1Z1 can be almost unplayable with this issue while shadows are enabled. ------------ See links: [Image-1](https://i.gyazo.com/6bcea495a90097a361df85aaecbcf216.jpg) and [Image-2](https://i.gyazo.com/7c6cebf65815ca5e7df68609a50b87cb.jpg)

Comment: Does this happen right away or after a bit of time? Might be worth checking temperature of GPU/CPU when this occurs, also check memory and cpu usage when this occurs.

Comment: It looks like video compression artifacts in the gif's, but if you actually see them on your screen in the actual game, that can mean one of few things: 1) your gpu is overheated and/or overclocked past it's capabilities, or 2) your gpu is dying. Or the rare possibility that it's your drivers that are broken and are doing this, but that seems unlikely, as drivers generally don't cause graphics artifacts like that.

Comment: "Windows 7 and Windows 10" do you mean you had Windows 7 and upgraded to 10? Or do you dual boot? Does the same problem happen in Windows 7, or is it just 10?

Comment: A quick google shows a few users having a problem with the Windows 10 drivers for that card, and I am aware of other issues where Windows 10 does not play nice with the drivers, at all.

Comment: I know this is old, but did you make sure you were actually using the Nvidia card, and not Intel's integrated graphics?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a NVidia card.

It probably is not a hardware problem as shadows are not 'special', so the issue would appear on any texture.

There is a big chance that it is Ambient Occlusion. Go to your NVidia Control Panel, open the '3D' menu and find the 'Ambient Occlusion' option. Turn it off. That should sort the issue out.

Answer (score -2):

The only time I ever saw something similar to this was when I had a dust clogged video card that was overheating. it got worse over time and eventually quit. the fact that it happens in all your games and operating systems would suggest a hardware problem.